# Orthogonal edges in ER diagram

Tags: dot

I'm trying to make an Entity-relationship diagram using the Graphviz DOT language. In my model I have a self-referencing relationship and here I would like the edges to be orthogonal, i.e. consist only of vertical and horizontal lines. Currently I have this diagram:

```
digraph G {
    edge [arrowhead = none]
    Entity [shape = box]
    Relationship [shape = diamond]
    Entity -> Relationship [headport = w, tailport = w]
    Relationship -> Entity [headport = e, tailport = e]
}
```

[image: E-R diagram with curved edges]

I tried adding `graph [splines = ortho]` but then the diagram renders like this:

[image: E-R diagram with wrongly rendered edges]

Any ideas? I'm using version 2.43.0 of DOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ortho** implementation is rather flawed, Here is a DIY version.  It adds invisible point-shaped nodes to each side of the two ER nodes and then draws edges to connect everything to look "ortho".

```
digraph G {
    splines=false
    edge [arrowhead = none]
    { rank=same
      Entity [shape = box]
      node [shape=point label="" style=invis]
      x1 [group=G1]
      x2 [group=g2]
      x1 -> Entity [tailclip=false]   
      Entity -> x2 [headclip=false]
    }
    { rank=same    
      Relationship [shape = diamond]
      node [shape=point  label="" style=invis]
      y1 [group=G1]
      y2 [group=g2]
      y1 -> Relationship [tailclip=false]   
      Relationship -> y2 [headclip=false]
    }

    x1 -> y1 [headclip=false tailclip=false]
    x2 -> y2 [headclip=false tailclip=false]
}
```

Giving:
[image]